# Opposite of the CSS Class

Tags: javascript, css

i am working on the req where i need to build the opposite animation of the CSS class as shown below
can someone help me out for the construction
below is the opposite class

```css
.tcs-animate-right {
  position:relative;
  animation-name: animateright;
  animation-duration: 0.75s;
}

@keyframes animateright {
  from { right:-100px; opacity:0 }
  to { right:0; opacity:1 }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class='tcs-animate-right'>tcs-animate-right</p>
</div>
```

Kindly help me out in order to animate the field in the opposite direction as shown in the above.

Answer (score 1):

Its quite simple. Just copy / paste your code and renamte it a bit. Then just change `-100px` to `100px`

```css
.tcs-animate-right {
  position:relative;
  animation-name: animateright;
  animation-duration: 0.75s;
}
.tcs-animate-left {
  position:relative;
  animation-name: animateleft;
  animation-duration: 0.75s;
}

@keyframes animateright {
  from { right:-100px; opacity:0 }
  to { right:0; opacity:1 }
}

@keyframes animateleft {
  from { right: 100px; opacity:0 }
  to { right:0; opacity:1 }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class='tcs-animate-right'>tcs-animate-right</p>
  <p class='tcs-animate-left'>tcs-animate-left</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

```css
.tcs-animate-right {
  position: relative;
  animation-name: animateright;
  animation-duration: 0.75s;
}

@keyframes animateright {
  from {
    right: -100px;
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    right: 0;
    opacity: 1
  }
}

.tcs-animate-opposite {
  position: relative;
  animation-name: animateopposite;
  animation-duration: 0.75s;
  right: -100px;
}

@keyframes animateopposite {
  from {
    right: 0px;
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    right: -100px;
    opacity: 1
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="tcs-animate-right">

  From Right To Left
</div>

<div class="tcs-animate-opposite">

  From Left To Right
</div>
```